# MySQL - extract the rows with a certain column not repeated

Tags: mysql, group-by

Let's say I have a table structured in this way:

```
Column1   Column2    Column3
   a        E           f
   b        E           g
   c        r           h
   d        E           i
```

I would like to obtain just two rows:

```
 a    E    f
 c    r    h
```

because I dn't want to take rows where Column2 value is repeated and in particular *I don't care which of the repeated rows to take, so the first of them would fit*.

I thought that doing this query would work, but it's not:

```
select * from db group by Column2 having column2 != ''
```

beacause I obtain exactly the same rows

---

Here is the real example

```
Tabe: mydb
Columns:
id  int(11) AI PK
client  varchar(45)
birth   datetime
email   varchar(45)
phone   varchar(45)


 id   client        birth                email           phone
'1', 'test', '2017-08-12 00:00:00', 'aaa@gmail.com', '57576765767'
'2', 'test', '2017-08-12 00:00:00', 'aaa@gmail.com', '45646456546'
'3', 'test', '2017-08-12 00:00:00', 'aaa@gmail.com', '35435353553'
'4', 'test', '2017-08-12 00:00:00', 'test1@r.com',   '12313212313'
'5', 'test', '2017-08-12 00:00:00', 'test4@r.com',   '23424234234'
```

Query:
    select * mydb group by email

Result: the same as before

Comment: what you mean doesnt work? Here is a [**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/PWXN38651) and works

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza uhm...that is strange. There must be some particular in the structure of my table that doesn't permit that behaviour because on my db it doesn't work

Comment: cri isn't a row in the data set ?????

Comment: Sorry, I just updated it

Comment: It's still not clear what you're after. Note that you are allowed to edit questions, including removing parts that make no sense.

Comment: JCO is mistaken. The returned dataset is indeterminate. The fact that it's 'correct' is coincidence. He's also far too highly decorated to be unaware of this fact.

Comment: @Strawberry OP say he doesn't care which row he get as long not repeat. So Indeterminate is actually OK.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Your answer is set against the context of the comment *the first of them would fit*. Anyway, you know well enough not to promote queries that return indeterminate results.

Comment: @Strawberry But he said *I don't care which of the repeated rows to take*

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Column2, Column1, Column3
FROM db
GROUP BY Column2
```

Might do it

--EDIT--

had forgotten `GROUP BY` !

--- EDIT 2 ---

```
create table mydb (id  int(11) Primary key AUTO_increment,
  client  varchar(45),
  birth   datetime,
  email   varchar(45),
  phone   varchar(45));

INSERT INTO mydb VALUES
    ('1', 'test', '2017-08-12 00:00:00', 'aaa@gmail.com', '57576765767'),
    ('2', 'test', '2017-08-12 00:00:00', 'aaa@gmail.com', '45646456546'),
    ('3', 'test', '2017-08-12 00:00:00', 'aaa@gmail.com', '35435353553'),
    ('4', 'test', '2017-08-12 00:00:00', 'test1@r.com',   '12313212313'),
    ('5', 'test', '2017-08-12 00:00:00', 'test4@r.com',   '23424234234');

SELECT DISTINCT email, client, birth, phone
FROM mydb
GROUP BY email;

# email, client, birth, phone
aaa@gmail.com, test, 2017-08-12 00:00:00, 57576765767
test1@r.com, test, 2017-08-12 00:00:00, 12313212313
test4@r.com, test, 2017-08-12 00:00:00, 23424234234
```

Comment: That doesnt work, you will get `AEF`, and `BEG` because are distinct but share same `E`

Comment: Ughhh, forgot the `GROUP BY`. Getting old

Comment: Well, on rextexter online tool this also works, but not on my table

Comment: Show exact table and data to debug. I manually created a copy and it works

Comment: It's really simple. If you don't know, don't post. It benefits nobody.

Comment: @Strawberry  I *know* and *it is* working, as shown above.

Comment: This just returns arbitrary (or, more precisely, indeterminate) results.

Comment: >"where Column2 value is repeated and in particular I don't care which of the repeated rows to take, so the first of them would fit."
Please read the name of the request and actual request, before making arbitrary (or, more precisely, incorrect) comments

Comment: OK, I'll give you a challenge. Find a query on this site posted by a user with over, say, 10K rep that includes both a GROUP BY clause and a DISTINCT modifier in the same query.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

This will fetch only the data matching distinct email with the value with minimum id in the group. you can change the min to max if you want the maximum id.

Note: the id should unique

**Query**:

```
select * from mydb where id IN( select min(id) from mydb group by email )
```